# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist - Azure database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, devise

After deploying a web app on Azure (via Linux Virtual Machine) I successfully access the home page (first page) but get this error when I try to login (top-right of the navabar):

[image: Error]

I looked up this issue and I saw other people had it. They solved it by resetting and migrating, but it does not work.
So far I have tried:

1. The following command correctly executes but does not solve the problem:

   `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`
2. Commenting out the user.rb file but it did not solve the issue

I think the error is due to the gem `devise` or gem `rails_admin`, But I cannot work out the solution.

**Gemfile :**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.6.0'

gem 'grape'

gem 'bootsnap', require: false

gem 'devise'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'

gem 'puma'

gem 'rails', '5.2.2'

gem 'redis'

gem "mini_magick"

gem "chartkick"

gem 'country-select'

gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.3'

gem 'activestorage-validator'

gem 'rubyzip', '>= 1.2.1'

gem 'axlsx', git: 'https://github.com/randym/axlsx.git', ref: 'c8ac844'

gem 'axlsx_rails'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3'

gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.5.0'

gem 'sassc-rails'

gem 'simple_form'

gem 'uglifier'

gem 'webpacker'

group :development do

gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'

end

group :development, :test do

gem 'pry-byebug'

gem 'pry-rails'

gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'

gem 'spring'

gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'

gem 'dotenv-rails'

end
```

Content of **database.yml** :

```
default: &default
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: utf-8
    database: caoee
    username: mat
    password: ***
    pool: 5
    pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
    <<: *default
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: utf-8
    database: caoee
    username: mat
    password: ***
    pool: 5

test:
    <<: *default
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: utf-8
    database: caoee
    username: mat
    password: ***
    pool: 5

production:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: utf-8
    database: caoee
    username: mat
    password: ***
    pool: 5
```

**Postgresql roles:**

List of roles

```
Role name | Attributes | Member of
-----------------------------------    
mat | Superuser, Create role, Create DB | {}

postgres | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS|{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running that command `RAILS_ENV=production ...` Locally? 
Because that will just run the command locally, with production settings.

You need to reset the database on your Azure server. I'm not familiar with the Azure CLI but I'm sure there's commands to reset the DB remotely.

Comment: Yes, I am running it on the Azure Virtual Machine I created, not on local